# Can find symbol variable Base64 what is the reason?

Tags: java

```
package com.cordys.report;

import java.io.FileInputStream; 

public class Encode
{


public static String encodeFileStream(String filePath) //file path ex : C:\Program Files\Cordys\Web\reports\I0001180.pdf
{    


 try
 {


   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("E:/CSS Document/Test.pdf");
   StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
   int lineLength = 72;
   byte[] buf = new byte[lineLength/4*3];
   while (true)
   {
     int len = fin.read(buf);
     if (len <= 0)
    {
      break;
    }
    sb.append(Base64.encode(buf));
   } 
   return sb.toString();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
   return e.getMessage();
 }

}


}
```

Comment: 1.) why are you trying to encode into separate lines? Every Base64 encoder worth its salt should be able to produce multi-line results without having to feed it appropriately-sized chunks.
2.) **returning** the exception message is an outstandingly bad way to deal with an excepton. There's no way for the caller to distinguish an error condition from a very short file.
3.) you ignore the `filePath` argument, which is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it means the compiler doesn't know where to find a class called Base64. (I doubt that it's meant to be a *variable*.) Steps:

- You haven't imported it, so the compiler is currently only looking in java.lang and com.cordys.report
- You'll need to make sure the class is on the classpath too, so that there's something for the compiler to find. Where are you expecting the Base64 class to be found?

Are you trying to use the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) library? If so, you'll need an import for `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` and make sure the appropriate jar file is in your classpath.

(As a side matter, I hope your *real* code takes note of how many bytes have actually been read, rather than encoding the whole buffer regardless. You should also close the file in a `finally` block, and take a rather more robust approach to handling exceptions.)

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported Base64 class. I suggest you use [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) for this. If you doesn't want to add additional library then JDK comes with an internal implementation which you can use (NOT recommended as this is not portable).

Comment: I have added requred jar files but it still throws error as follows:nonstatic method encode(byte[])cannot be referenced from static content