# java error unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream; 

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Encode 
{

    //file path ex : C:\Program Files\Cordys\Web\reports\I0001180.pdf
    public static String encodeFileStream(String filePath) throws Exception 
    {    

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

        try 
        {

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            //StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            int lineLength = 72;
            byte[] buf = new byte[lineLength/4*3];

            while (true) 
            {
                int len = fin.read(buf);
                if (len <= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                //new Base64().encode(byte);
                //sb.append(Base64.encode(buf));
                //sb.append(Base64.encodeBase64(buf));

                Base64 b = new Base64();
                sb.append(b.encode(buf)); 

                //return sb.toString();
            }
        }  

        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s="";

        s=encodeFileStream("E:/CSSDocument/Test.pdf");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why create a new user? You've [had one before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779444/can-find-symbol-variable-base64-what-is-the-reason). Also: my comments on that other question still apply.

Comment: You create `Base64 b = new Base64();` within the while-loop. You programm may run faster, if you create it before the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @Joachim It seems you are in too hurry and left to close this

Comment: @org.life.java: white the question is about the same code, it's not in fact the same question.

Comment: @Joachim , ah.. I saw just same code , didn't see the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Your method "encodeFileStream" throws Exception. You are catching it in that method so you don't need to declare it in your method declaration.

Either:

1. Remove "throws Exception" from the declaration of encodeFileStream, or
2. Add "throws Exception" to the declaration of main(String[] args)

Comment: Or 3. Catch exception in the main() method. I had no idea that main() can have a "throws" declaration, but even so, what would be the point of it?

Comment: @Sergey There isn't really a point to it. I use it when I create little test programs. All it does is close the program logging the Exception to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

You don't catch the Exception, which may be thrown by `encodeFileStream()`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String s="";
    s=encodeFileStream("E:/CSSDocument/Test.pdf");
}
```

would help, but this is not what I would call "Good exception handling".